# AWS Serialisation error on front end

Tags: craft3, assets, s3, aws

Getting the following error on a site I'm developing:

> Instances of craft\awss3\S3Client cannot be serialized

Unsure if this is an issue with the Amazon S3 plugin or at my bucket's end. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Note this only happens on initial page load. If I reload the page the error is gone and my assets load fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a minor bug in 3.3.0.1. Fixed now.